# Newbie looking for help on a password code

Tags: java, passwords, generator

I am looking for some help with a project i am working on. I am relatively new to java and am working to make a function to generate a password. There is probably alot of error in this or this might be completely wrong so please be nice to a newbie >.<

```
import java.util.Random;

public class StillTesting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Your new password is: " + generateValidPassword());
    }

    static private String generateValidPassword() {
        String numcase = "";
        String lowcase = "";
        String upcase = "";
        String halfpass = numcase.concat(upcase);
        String returnString = halfpass.concat(lowcase);

        System.out.print(returnString);

        Random r = new Random();

        String loweralphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int n = loweralphabet.length();

        String upperalphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        int N = upperalphabet.length();

        int num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            num = r.nextInt(9);

            numcase = String.valueOf(num = r.nextInt(9));
            return numcase;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            lowcase = String.valueOf(loweralphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(n)));
            return lowcase;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            upcase = String.valueOf(upperalphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N)));
            return upcase;
        }
        return returnString;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this code not working? What is your question?

Comment: when i run the code it only spits out 1 number. thats it.

Comment: what should the expected output be?

Comment: The problem is you are returning in your for loop.  It will return the first iteration and only return one value.

Comment: You're `return`ing from your function inside the first loop so any further execution is abandoned at that point.

Comment: numcase = String.valueOf(**num=r.nextInt(9)**); are you sure your code rusn?

Comment: the code is compiling but i am sure something is done wrong. when i remove the return statements where would i move them to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try removing your return statements in your loop something like this:

```
static private String generateValidPassword() 
{ 
    String numcase = "";
    String lowcase = "";
    String upcase = "";
    String halfpass = "";
    String returnString = "";

    System.out.print(returnString);

    Random r = new Random();

    String loweralphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   int n = loweralphabet.length();

   String upperalphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   int N = upperalphabet.length();

   int num = 0;
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
       num=r.nextInt(9);

       numcase = String.valueOf(num);
       returnString += numcase;
   }
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
       lowcase = String.valueOf(loweralphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(n)));
       returnString += lowcase;
   }
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
       upcase = String.valueOf(upperalphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N)));
       returnString += upcase;
   }
   return returnString;
 }
```

This will give you output like 637xiqHMR.  You will combine the letters generated from each loop into one string then return the whole string at the end instead of returning at first iteration of first loop.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? The output of the following program is something like `433raeWPV` and `675croJWV`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Your new password is: " + generateValidPassword());
}

static private String generateValidPassword() {

    String pswd = "";

    Random r = new Random();

    String loweralphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int n = loweralphabet.length();

    String upperalphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int N = upperalphabet.length();

    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        num = r.nextInt(9);

        pswd += String.valueOf(num = r.nextInt(9));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        pswd += String.valueOf(loweralphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(n)));

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        pswd += String.valueOf(upperalphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N)));

    }
    return pswd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, indeed there are some mistakes:

1. You are setting halfpass and returnString values before assigning the values of numcase, upcase and lowcase
2. You are returning a value in the first iteration of every for loop, The first return statement will return the first numcase value. More info about how the return statement works [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

at the end,  the returnString statement is never reached.

Try something like this:

```
 static private String generateValidPassword() 
 { 
     String numcase = "";
     String lowcase = "";
     String upcase = "";


     Random r = new Random();

     String loweralphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int n = loweralphabet.length();

    String upperalphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int N = upperalphabet.length();

    int num = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        num=r.nextInt(9);
        numcase += String.valueOf( num = r.nextInt(9));

    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        lowcase += String.valueOf(loweralphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(n)));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        upcase += String.valueOf(upperalphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N)));
    }
     String halfpass = numcase.concat(upcase);
     String returnString = halfpass.concat(lowcase);

    System.out.print(returnString);
    return returnString;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like a few people spotted the bugs while I was working, but as I've tidied up the whole thing you might like to take a look at this working version which addresses most of the issues in the original:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class StillTesting {

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println("Your new password is: " + generateValidPassword());
    }

    static private String generateValidPassword()
    {
        StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();

        Random r = new Random();

        final String loweralphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        final String upperalphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            password.append(String.valueOf(r.nextInt(10)));
        }
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            password.append(loweralphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(loweralphabet.length())));
        }
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            password.append(upperalphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(upperalphabet.length())));
        }

        return password.toString();
    }
}
```